# Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttribute' error in platform.js and IE11

Tags: javascript, polymer, internet-explorer-11

Getting the following error from IE 11 and Polymer/platform

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttribute'
File: platform.js, Line: 12, Column: 30816
```

I have following meta decalared.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge, chrome=1" />
```

The site is working perfectly in Chrome. So I guess its must be a comparability issue. Any Idea?

Comment: Can you post a test page?

Comment: The question should be in the body of your post. Post a minimal example that displays the error here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XHTML, then the self-closing tags may be an issue:

> Serving the page as XHTML will permit self-closing tags, BUT breaks some scripts.
>
> For example, I created this element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>
<polymer-element name="copyright-statement" attributes="copyrightStart">
  <template>
    <span>
      &#169; {{copyrightStart}}{{thisYear}}
    </span>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('copyright-statement',{
        copyrightStart:2014,
        created: function() {
            console.log("The copyright-statement has been registered.");
        },
        ready: function() {
            this.thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
            if(this.copyrightStart != null) {
                if(parseInt(this.copyrightStart) < this.thisYear) {
                    this.copyrightStart = this.copyrightStart + " \u2014 ";
                } else {
                    this.copyrightStart = "";
                }
            }
        }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**References**

- [Issue #680: Polymer should respect XHTML syntax](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/680)
- [DOM Level 2 - Core: Section 1.2, Fundamental Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff460299)